# Apache POI. Parsing a formula to obtain the Cell.Type of operands

Tags: java, apache-poi, spreadsheet

I am trying to obtain the cell.Type of formulas present in the excel sheet. I have used Apache POI to extract the formulas. What I want to do is something like this:

```
Cell D3 = PRODUCT (A3,C3). Where possibly C3 = SUMN(B3,1). I would like to get the Cell.Type of Each operands i.e. 

D3 = PRODUCT('NUMERIC/DOUBLE', 'FORMULA') or D3 = PRODUCT ('NUMERIC/DOUBLE', 'SUM('NUMERIC/INTEGER', 'NUMERIC/INTEGER')')
```

Below is where I am currently in reading the spreadsheet

```
public class test {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    
FileInputStream ExcelFile = new FileInputStream(new File("data/smpl.xlsx"));
XSSFWorkbook book1 = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFile);
XSSFEvaluationWorkbook evaluationWorkbook = XSSFEvaluationWorkbook.create(book1);
XSSFSheet sheet = book1.getSheetAt(0);
System.out.println(sheet);
System.out.println("Formulae........");
Iterator<Row> rowiter = sheet.iterator();
while (rowiter.hasNext()) {
XSSFRow row = (XSSFRow) rowiter.next();
if (row.getRowNum() == 2) {
    Iterator cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
        XSSFCell cell = (XSSFCell) cellIterator.next();
        //System.out.println(cell.getReference());
        if (cell.getCellType() == CellType.FORMULA){
            System.out.println(cell.getAddress() + " = " +cell.getCellFormula() + ", Value = " +cell.getNumericCellValue());
            Ptg[] ptg = FormulaParser.parse(cell.getCellFormula(), evaluationWorkbook, FormulaType.CELL, 0);
            for (int i=0;i<ptg.length;i++){
                System.out.println (ptg[i].toFormulaString());
            }
//                          Ptg[] ptg1 = FormulaParser.parse(cell.getCellFormula(), evaluationWorkbook, FormulaType.NAMEDRANGE, 0);
//                          for (int i=0;i<ptg1.length;i++){
//                              System.out.println (ptg1[i]);
//                          }
                
    } } } } }
```

[image]

I have tried using the Ptg package. This is what it outputs for now.

```
Formulae........
C3 = PRODUCT(A3,B3), Value = 8.0

A3
B3
PRODUCT

{   /* RefPtg */
  "row": 2
, "rowRelative": true
, "column": 0
, "colRelative": true
, "formatReference": "A3"
}
{   /* RefPtg */
  "row": 2
, "rowRelative": true
, "column": 1
, "colRelative": true
, "formatReference": "B3"
}
{   /* FuncVarPtg */
  "functionIndex": 183 /* 0x00b7 */
, "functionName": "PRODUCT"
, "numberOfOperands": 2
, "externalFunction": false
, "defaultOperandClass": 32 /* 0x20 */
, "cetab": false
}
```

Any pointers on using the formula parser on the extracted formula to obtain the Cell.Type?

Something like this:

```
D3 = PRODUCT('NUMERIC/DOUBLE', 'FORMULA') or D3 = PRODUCT ('NUMERIC/DOUBLE', 'SUM('NUMERIC/INTEGER', 'NUMERIC/INTEGER')')
```

Comment: This seems to be a XY problem to me. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Why do you think to need that information?

Comment: This is to collate formulas. Mostly the user-defined one. While doing that trying to collect as much meta-information as possible. E.g. at times, the formula might be just to CONCAT (A3, 'Newyork').

Comment: Have you tried https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getCachedFormulaResultType-- ?

Comment: If you need the type of the formula operands, I doubt whether POI exposes them in a publicly accessible way. Its FormulaEvaluator is just built to calculate the value for the formula. You might be able to write some custom code that uses the Formula Evaluator as a template.